Code not executing after initializing new Ethers Interface
I'm trying to use Ethers to create an ABI interface that I can use to query block specific data with Alchemy. The document I'm referencing is https://docs.alchemy.com/docs/how-to-get-erc-20-token-balance-at-a-given-block#step-5-get-usdt-balance-at-a-particular-block. This doc is utilizing Ethers v5.x but I was able to find the equivalent changes for v6.x. The issue I'm running into is that essentially none of my code executes AFTER trying to initialize a new interface via ethers.
const getBalance = async (walletAddress) => {
  ...
  console.log("CREATING INTERFACE");
  // Create function call data -- eth_call
  let iface = new ethers.Interface([
    "function balanceOf(address) view returns (uint)"
  ]);
  // code below this comment never gets executed
  console.log("IFACE", iface);

  let data = iface.encodeFunctionData("balanceOf", [walletAddress]);
  console.log("DATA", data);

  // Get balance at a particular block -- usage of eth_call
  let balancedData = await alchemy.core.call({
    to: USDC_CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
    data: data,
  }, blockTag);

  return (parseInt(balancedData) / 10 ** FIXED_DECIMAL_PLACE).toFixed(2);
}

I'm not seeing any errors in the console either so this is becoming difficult to solve or even look for solutions.

It's working fine for me though. Can you please check your package.json and confirm that ethers is installed correctly?

Also, were you able to get the token balance without using ethers as mentioned in Step-4 of the same doc?

My issue ended up being that i was importing ethers via import { ethers } from 'ethers'. Once I changed it to const ethers = require('ethers') then it worked lol. There goes 3 hours.
